# Icon are bolder in white

Tags: css, web, font-face, antialiasing

I'm working on a web project. I'd like to display a [fonticon](https://icomoon.io/#icons-lindua) within some buttons and set the color to white. However it seems that changing the foreground color changes the weight of the icon. On this image, both the two buttons are the same classes and properties, only differs the color attribute.

[image]

I tried to overlay those two and the result shows that indeed those two width are slightly different which causes a huge difference when those are displayed in their real size.

[image]

Following [this link](http://www.lighterra.com/articles/macosxtextaabug/) I tried to play with those:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

without any success.

Do you have any clue on any css property that may interfer with the thickness of those icons?

Is this related to the font itself ?

EDIT:

Screenshot with real size
[image]

Comment: can you share the vector icon?

Answer (score 2):

Icons are **not** bolder in white.

Most likely, it is your eye that perceives them that way, because white provides a greater contrast with current `background-color` than black.

But, from a technical perspective, font glyphs have the same dimensions regardless of color. In fact, considering current font technology, it is impossible to provide different shapes based on current `font-color`.

However, even though at page level the font glyphs always have the same size, it is possible that either the browser used or the operating system are modifying the rendered output based on algorithms aimed at **increasing text readability**.

Simply turning those options off (at browser or OS level, depending on where they are defined) should fix the problem (where by *"problem"* we mean: *"the rendered shape has different dimensions in snapshots taken from the same page"*).

Comment: i suppose to say the same.. but i took the whole image to illustrator and measured then observed that its really thicker than the black one, even the size of icon is also differs

Comment: If what you say is true, either the tool used for rendering (the browser) or the snapshot tool are flawed. What you're claiming (having a font with different shape based on color) is technically impossible with current font techniques. Most likely, the browser or the system are modifying the output to increase readability. Either way, it's not at page level, it's above it.

Comment: I agree with  You.. Andrei

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used the term "bolder" as a way of speaking, I knew the icons where not "boldered" but it was only a render issue. What's a pity is that with this behaviour my icons are blurry / glitchy in white where they're not in black without nothing I can do. No configuration nor settings seem to be available to bypass this behaviour. I'm kind of stuck for nothing.

Comment: @Florent, If you're on a Windows machine, you might want to have a look under Display Settings > Scale and layout > Advanced scaling settings > Let Windows try to fix apps so they're not blurry. Turn it off.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu already tried to play with those without no success :(

Comment: Have you also looked at browser level? What browser are you using? Could you also provide a *runnable* [mcve] displaying the problem? I'd like to have a look at it and try different tricks to see if I can get it rendered sharper.